# Foreign car insurance for Kosovo

Tags: insurance

My car Peugeot 3008 is registered as a truck.
What is the price of the border insurance policy for Kosovo for 15 days or the price is the same - 15 Euro?

I plan to buy it from [PolicaOnline.](https://api.bks-ks.org/PolicaOnline/en-GB)